# Rcl init failed to find shared library of rmw implementation

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed ROS2 Dashing via the Debian package (desktop). The demo listener crashes after failing to find the Fast RTPS library (default RMW).

```
$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
what():  failed to initialized rcl init options: failed to find shared library of rmw implementation.   Searched rmw_fastrtps_cpp, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-dashing-rmw-implementation-0.7.1/src/functions.cpp:130, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-dashing-rcl-0.7.4/src/rcl/init_options.c:55
$ locate librmw_fastrtps_cpp.so 
/opt/ros/dashing/lib/librmw_fastrtps_cpp.so
$ env | grep ROS
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_DISTRO=dashing
$ ldconfig -p | grep libfastrtps
libfastrtps.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/ros/dashing/lib/libfastrtps.so.1
libfastrtps.so (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/ros/dashing/lib/libfastrtps.so
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/home/fireman/ros2_examples_ws/install/examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition/lib:/opt/ros/dashing/opt/yaml_cpp_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/dashing/opt/rviz_ogre_vendor/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/ros/dashing/lib
```

My Linux distribution is Ubuntu 18.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325705/rcl-init-failed-to-find-shared-library-of-rmw-implementation/) by [ananya.muddu](https://answers.ros.org/users/42686/ananya.muddu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-06-13**:
On ubuntu that should search [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_implementation/blob/85ef0c09ad53d4dbc0b029e39cb8c237f795d39f/rmw_implementation/src/functions.cpp#L95). What is the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Was that variable modified after sourcing `/opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash`?

**Comment by [ananya.muddu](https://answers.ros.org/users/42686/ananya.muddu/) on 2019-06-14**:
@sloretz: Thanks! I have edited the question to include LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the ldconfig cache. No problems there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was bitten by this issue as well.

Make sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set. This is important, even if the librmw_fastrtps_cpp.so file exists in /usr/lib, since the RMW code will explicitly look for LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

See also this interesting issue: https://github.com/ros2/rcpputils/issues/40

---

Originally posted by [Windel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20680/windel/) with karma: 36 on 2020-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0